# Trigger Github Action after CircleCI workflow or job

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, github-actions, continuous-deployment, circleci

I would like to set up github actions in order to perform security scans on docker images. However, the build and push of the image I would like to scan is made by CircleCI. Hence I need to make sure that the images have been properly built and pushed on my repo before performing the security scan.

I know there exists an action to trigger a CircleCI job, but is there any way to trigger the execution of my Github action from Circle CI?

Thank you for the answers or any workaround you could provide :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a [repository dispatch event](https://docs.github.com/pt/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-dispatch-event) from you CircleCI pipeline to start a repository workflow (through CURL or through a script).

In that case, your Github repository workflow file will need a [repository_dispatch](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#repository_dispatch) event to trigger it, to perform your security scan job.

**Dispatch Request Example**

```
curl \
 -X POST \
 -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
 https://api.github.com/repos/<USERNAME>/<REPOSITORY-NAME>/dispatches \
 -d '{"event_type":"event_type"}'
```

**Workflow Trigger Example**

```
on: [repository_dispatch]

jobs:
  scan:
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
   steps:
     - name: security scan
       run:|
        ...
```

Comment: Didn't know about this Github feature. Seems to answer my issue, I will try to implement this and see if it behaves corretcly. I have thought to a similar solution by installing Github client on animage and use it on my job to trigger the action but your solution seems more fast forward. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: You can even use this to trigger workflows between different Github repositories. Feel free to contact me if you have any question 